# Transfer data using local only hotspot

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a local hotspot using this code:

```
wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(object :WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback(){
            override fun onStarted(reservation: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation?) {
                super.onStarted(reservation)
            }

            override fun onFailed(reason: Int) {
                super.onFailed(reason)
            }
        }, null)
```

I want to get connected devices and transfer data between them (a local messenger). Is it possible? If yes how can I send data